# Add React components from plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

**Background**

I don't have much React experience. I'm writing an embeddable widget using React and Redux. This widget can be included multiple times on the same web page, each with its own settings.

**Problem**

I'd like to only include the React app JS once. So that if the widget gets included multiple times on a single page it loads the app JS the first time, then for each subsequent include it checks if the JS is already included and if so doesn't again.

So far I'm only able to initialise the first widget instance, which happens when the React app JS is loaded. I'm thinking I'd like to make a lightweight (vanilla JavaScript) call for each subsequent widget that renders a React component with that widget's settings to the DOM.

I can't seem to figure out how to do a plain JavaScript call to make React render a new component.

**What it looks like**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/widget/1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/widget/2"></script>
```

The first script tag adds a script tag to the page with the main React app JS. It's a big file, ~800 KB. It contains all the React/Redux library inclusions and my React component definitions. It renders a React component and passes it the ID 1.

The second script tag really shouldn't include that file again for the sake of creating a new component on the page. I just want it to render a new React component in the DOM and pass it the ID 2.

Comment: If you're building a widget which will be included in multiple websites. I suggest you do server side rendering and include it in an iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To render a React element, just call:

```
ReactDOM.render(react_element, dom_element);
```

Where dom_element is the place you want your react element to go in the page.  [Relevant docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/rendering-elements.html).

If you want to guard against multiple inclusion of JavaScript, just write your script so that it first checks if it has already run, and then exits immediately if it has.

Of course, your widget will also need to load the React scripts and wait until they are ready before proceeding.  You can do that like this:

```
if (!window.MyWidgetPromise) {
  window.MyWidgetPromise = script([
    'https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js',
    'https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js'       
  ]).then(function() {
    return React.createClass(...);
  })
}
window.MyWidgetPromise.then(function(widget) {
  ReactDOM.render(widget, TARGET_ELEMENT);
})
```

Assuming you're using [this promise-based script loader](https://bradb.net/blog/promise-based-js-script-loader/).

Alternatively, you could have the first inclusion of this widget render all instances of the widget that are needed in the page, and have subsequent inclusions do nothing, like so:

```
if (!window.MyWidgetPromise) {
  window.MyWidgetPromise = script([
    'https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js',
    'https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js'       
  }).then(function() {
    var widget = React.createClass(...);
    document.querySelector('my-widget').forEach(function(element) {
      ReactDOM.render(widget, element);
    })
  })
}
```

Though this would work better if it was wrapped in a document ready handler so you can be sure that all the effected elements will exist in the DOM before the querySelector runs.

Comment: Thank you. Excuse my ignorance, but I if call that from a plain JavaScript it can't find ReactDOM.

Comment: You'll have to include react into the page.  Try using the ones from this CDN: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html#using-a-cdn .  To wait until they're loaded before using them, try adding an onload event handler to the script tags.